# Moq testing if method1 calls second method2 in same class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I'm new to Moq

I read a lot about `Moq` testing and that you shouldn't test your mock object, instead you should use Moq to stub dependencies and make it to act like you want to. But now I am asking myself, how can you test if a method  be called from another method in the same class, like this code:

```
public class A // --> class i want to test
{
  public virtual void TestMethod() // --> does it call testmethod2
  {
    TestMethod2();
  }

  public virtual void TestMethod2()
  {
    // Do something
  }
}
```

I thought I can write the Unittest like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void MyTestMethod()
{
  Mock<A> aMock = new Mock<A>();
  aMock.Verify(o => o.TestMethod2(), Times.Once);

  aMock.TestMethod();

  aMock.VerifyAll();
}
```

But is this valid? Thank you for all good answers!

Comment: Most likely there is no reason to mock at all, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56078171/when-to-use-mock-objects-in-unit-tests/56102108#56102108

Answer (score 0):

Moq is only able to mock out methods which are virtual (or provide mock implementations for interfaces). If you try a `Setup` or `Verify` on a non-virtual member, you'll get the error

> Invalid verify on a non-virtual member: m => m.TestMethod2()

In your case, you would need to change `TestMethod2` to virtual, i.e.

```
public virtual void TestMethod2()
```

Which can then be tested:

```
var aMock = new Mock<A>();

aMock.Object.TestMethod();

aMock.Verify(m => m.TestMethod2(), Times.Once);
```

As you've suggested, testing whether a class calls methods internal to itself is a smell, indication that you're either

- Testing internal implementation detail (e.g. if `TestMethod2()` was private, it's none of our business to even know about it).
- Or, an indication that the Class / System under test is in need of refactoring into multiple classes, which should be loosely coupled, and hence can be isolated and better testable.

**Note**

- You can't `Verify` a call before you've invoked the method on the SUT that you want to test, i.e. move the `Verify` to after the invocation of `.TestMethod()` as I've done.
- Although you could change your code to use the `Setup` + `VerifyAll` approach to testing, i.e. ensuring that everything you've setup is actually invoked:

```
aMock.Setup(m => m.TestMethod2());

aMock.Object.TestMethod();

aMock.VerifyAll();
```

There is however debate around whether the usage of `VerifyAll` violates `AAA` principals (since you're also in effect specifying the `Verify` criteria in the `Arrange` piece), and I've also found that this approach makes it impossible to refactor and DRY up Mock setups in large scale tests, and you also lose some of the finer level of checking (e.g. `Times.Once`).