# python - mock and unit test a chain of methods that change input list

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I have a list of filters and each filter changes the input list. How do I create a mock for each filter that will change the input list?

```
class TwoFilter(object):

    def filter(self, arr):
        arr[:] = [i for i in arr if i % 2 != 0]

class ThreeFilter(object):

    def filter(self, arr):
        arr[:] = [i for i in arr if i % 3 != 0]

class FourFilter(object):

    def filter(self, arr):
        arr[:] = [i for i in arr if i % 3 != 0]

class MyFilters(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.filters = [TwoFilter(), ThreeFilter(), FourFilter()]

    def apply_filters(self, arr):
        for f in self.filters:
            f.filter(arr)
```

I want to unit test `apply_filters` by mocking the filters in `self.filters` for input [1,2,3,4]. Is there a way to have each mock change the input `arr` and verify if each subsequent filter was called with this modified `arr`?

P.S: I am able to get around this problem by having the filters return the `arr` and use `mock.return_value` to change the mock's output.

Answer (score 0):

As you spoke of mocking the filter classes, I take it that your approach is to also test the filter classes individually as well?  This should certainly still be done, and better done as the first step - if I am not mistaken reading your code, you will likely discover a bug then.

Regarding the test of `apply_filters`: Why do you want to mock the filter classes at all?  There seems to be no justification - you can just call `apply_filters` with some suitable values for `arr` to see if the other filters are actually called.  And, maybe you find the next bug then (after correcting the first) - just try to find a test case that fails if the third filter is not called.

Mocking should be done for a reason - take a look at [When to use mock objects in unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56078171/when-to-use-mock-objects-in-unit-tests/56102108#56102108).